# NGNIX libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: nginx

I'm try to install NGNIX but when i type `systemctl status nginx.service` 
got this error message:

> /usr/sbin/nginx: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

then i use ldd to check the link. the link was correct.
here's i use ldd result:
ldd:

> ibperl.so => /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so (0x00007f90f5ebf000)

find the reason was ldconfig miss the link.But after i rebuild ldconfig got this error:

> /usr/sbin/nginx: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/nginx: undefined symbol: Perl_save_strle

how to resolve it?

Comment: I have the same error. In my case I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, with Nginx installed from the ppa stable 
Did you find a solution?

Comment: I tried Nginx mailine, 1.11.1, but that has same problem.
Ubuntu has libperl.so.5.22.1, so I guess that's the reason.
(Oh for snappy packages!).

I just read your post again, and you don't have the file at all.
In which case its package  libperl-dev that's missing.
In my case I have libperl.so.22.1 but need libperl.so.20

Comment: I've built from 1.10.1 source without problem using default modules, and it's running. But it's tomorrow's job to check I have what modules I need